# pip install mod_wsgi fails in virtualenv

Tags: django, python-2.7, virtualenv, mod-wsgi, django-wsgi

I'm trying to install mod_wsgi using pip in python 2.7.10 on mac os 10.12 inside a virtualenv. I intend to use it in a a Django 1.10.3.
When I run "pip install mod_wsgi" I get the following output:

```
Collecting mod_wsgi
Using cached mod_wsgi-4.5.7.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/sf/kdqqs98d06326180mss7hggh0000gn/T/pip-build-hgA7s1/mod-wsgi/setup.py", line 247, in <module>
    APR_INCLUDES = get_apr_includes().split()
  File "/private/var/folders/sf/kdqqs98d06326180mss7hggh0000gn/T/pip-build-hgA7s1/mod-wsgi/setup.py", line 219, in get_apr_includes
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/sf/kdqqs98d06326180mss7hggh0000gn/T/pip-build-hgA7s1/mod-wsgi/
```

I'm new to virtualenv so it might be that I'm just missing something with how to set that up. I've tried upgrading pip, reinstalling setuptools and ez_setup via pip.

Comment: Do you have the Xcode command line tools installed? Does ``xcode-select --install`` say they are installed when run?

Comment: Running that command prompted me to run the installation. I went ahead and installed the command line tools. I am still getting the same issue though when running pip install mod_wsgi.

Comment: Does the program ``/usr/sbin/apxs`` exist? Can you find ``apxs`` anywhere on your system? Can use ``find / -name apxs``. Apple breaks installation of Apache modules and mod_wsgi on every new major OS update and this time it looks like they don't install ``apxs`` in the normal place.

Comment: But then. It is present on my spare laptop where I have updated to Sierra. They may have made it necessary to install full Xcode itself, but that shouldn't really be necessary. Was your Sierra a fresh install or an upgrade from Yosemite.

Comment: `/usr/sbin/apxs` does exist and apxs works in the terminal. I had installed xcode before, but when I launched it this time it had to reinstall. (upgrading to Sierra might have been the reason for that) Even after the install I got the same error though.

Comment: What do you get if you run ``/usr/sbin/apxs -q APR_CONFIG``. If that gives a path to a program with name something like ``apr-1-config``, does that program exist?

Comment: Running that seems to indicate that apr-1-config does not exist: `Sandwichs-MacBook-Pro:sbin sandwich$ /usr/sbin/apxs -q APR_CONFIG
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin/apr-1-config
apxs:Error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin/apr-1-config not found!.
Sandwichs-MacBook-Pro:sbin sandwich$ `

Comment: That would suggest that Xcode is now a requirement to install mod_wsgi. Did you have Xcode installed? What is in the directory ``/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains`` if you believe it is installed.

Comment: Note that when say Xcode I mean the full Xcode application and not just command line tools.

Comment: I can launch Xcode and have used it with C++ code previously so I'm pretty confident it is installed. The Toolchains folder contains `Swift_2.3.xctoolchain` and `XcodeDefault.xctoolchain`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two problems with installing mod_wsgi on MacOS X Sierra.

The first problem is that Apple has made the default Apache installation they provide entirely unusable when it comes to being able to install third party Apache modules. This builds on top of obstacles they already had in prior MacOS X versions which meant you had to jump through hoops to get it working.

The issue in this case is that Apple has removed the `apr-1-config` and `apu-1-config` programs from the Xcode distribution. This means that `apxs` will fail when certain types of queries are made about the Apache configuration that exists. This is information that is needed to build third party modules for Apache. Without knowing where header files are installed, builds of Apache modules will fail.

Given Apple's history of breaking the ability to install additional Apache modules in every OS update, and never fixing it for the life of the OS, thus requiring workarounds, it is unlikely once again that they will fix this problem.

In other forums one suggestion to get around the problem is to install APR and APU packages with brew and then symlink the `apr-1-config` and `apu-1-config` programs from those into the location `apxs` is looking. This to me looks error prone as it seems that modules then might be compiled against brew header files and these may not match the library version for those provided by the operating system Apache installation. That could result in crashes.

The only guaranteed solution is therefore not to use the Apache installation supplied with the operating system.

So one option may be to use brew to install Apache and use the brew installation of Apache (not just APR and APU from brew).

Another option if using `pip install mod_wsgi` method, is to first use the `pip` installable Apache provided for `mod_wsgi`.

```
pip install -vvv mod_wsgi-httpd
```

Using this should only be done where have no choice and you should always use the system Apache if you can. Right now we don't seem to have a choice.

This will install Apache into the Python installation or virtual environment. It will take a bit of time as it is going to compile/install APR/APU/Apache and possibly other required libraries as well. Am using `-vvv` so you can see it doing the compilation else you might think it has hung.

Once that is done then run `pip install mod_wsgi`.

This is only useful if using `mod_wsgi-express`. You can't use this if then want to use the compiled mod_wsgi with the operating system Apache as the module built this way will be incompatible with the operating system Apache.

The second problem is that MacOS X Sierra changed operating system APIs for getting process task information. This will mean mod_wsgi 4.5.7 and earlier will fail to compile anyway. There is a fix coming in mod_wsgi 4.5.8, or you can use code from the mod_wsgi github repository until 4.5.8 is released if need to.

---

UPDATE 1

Managed to include a hack in `setup.py` for when doing `pip install mod_wsgi`. This will also be in mod_wsgi 4.5.8. It means you can still use the system Apache and don't need to install a separate one such as by using `pip install mod_wsgi-httpd`. This will not solve similar problems with for `configure/make` method for installing mod_wsgi.

Comment: Installing apache via brew seemed to do the trick! Thanks for such a robust and clear answer!

Comment: this is not working in centos cpanel also, any help?

Comment: @xyz Create a new question. Don't ask your question as a comment.

Comment: You are on CentOS. This question was about a specific issue with macOS. How can it be the same issue? Create a new question with the exact details of your specific problem.